# Convert DateTime format MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss GMT+5.0 to UTC

Tags: c#, valueconverter

I want to convert **13/MAR/2015 11:26:26 GMT -6.00** to UTC. I know how to convert ,if it is in some standard time,i have converted it using following code.

```
 string dateTime = "13/MAR/2015 11:26:26";    
 TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Cental standard Time");
 TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime), zone);
```

But i want to convert **13/MAR/2015 11:26:26  GMT -6.00** to UTC.Please help me.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your problem is basically how to convert a string to a DateTime, right?
Consider looking into DateTime.Parse, in particular, this overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Not that .I have to handle GMT -6.00 & it has to convert to UTC

Comment: The biggest issue with your date time string, is that the offset is specified in a format that is unsupported. It is `-6.00` instead of `-06:00`, which does not allow it to be parsed directly using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.ToUniversalTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example

```
        string dateTime = "13/MAR/2015 11:26:26";
        TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
        var local = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime), zone);
        var offcet = zone.GetUtcOffset(local);
        string output = local + " GMT " + offcet.Hours;
```

Comment: gal peled here i dont know the --- Standard Time,If i kno the exact standrd time i will handle that

Comment: i want this format string dateTime ="13/MAR/2015 11:26:26 GMT -6.00"

Comment: just add the GMT and the offcet to the string like this string dateTime = "13/MAR/2015 11:26:26";
            TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
            var local = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime), zone);
            var offcet = zone.GetUtcOffset(local);
            string output = local + "GMT " + offcet.Hours;

Answer (score 1):

The problem with parsing that string is that the time zone name is not recognised, and the offset is in the format `-6.00` instead of `-6:00`.

Remove the time zone name, and change the offset format, and you can parse the date, then you can use the `ToUniversalTime` method to convert it to UTC:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(dateTime.Replace(" GMT ", " ").Replace(".", ":"));
DateTime utc = t.ToUniversalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

GMT is equal to UTC (though not the same exact thing) so you can replace the GMT in the string with UTC and parse the timezone from there.

Comment: i got System.FormatException'  for that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in one go. The problem is that the format of your date time strings contains a timezone offset component in an unsupported format: `-6.00` instead of `-06:00`. If that was not the case, you could directly parse your string in the following manner:

```
var myDateTime = "13/MAR/2015 11:26:26 GMT -06:00";
var fmt = "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT' zzz";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(myDateTime, fmt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var utcTime = dto.UtcDateTime;
```

You have to hack it by doing:

```
var myDateTime = "13/MAR/2015 11:26:26 GMT -6.00";
var fmt = "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT' zzz";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(myDateTime.Replace(".", ":")), fmt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var utcTime = dto.UtcDateTime;
```